# Some kind of intermediate value theorem for Lebesgue measure

Tags: continuity

I have this problem that I can't get my head around. 
Consider a Lebesgue measurable set $A$ with $0<\mu(A)<+\infty$. Define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\mu(A\cap(-\infty,x])$. Prove:

a) $f$ is continuous.

b) There exists a measurable set $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(B)=\mu(A)/2$.

c) There exists a compact set $C\subset A$ such that $\mu(C)=\mu(A)/2$.

For a), I chose a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ and proved $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)$, easy peasy.

Also for b), since $f$ continuous and assumes values in $[0,\mu(A)]$, we can find $x$ such that $B=(-\infty,x)\cap A$ has measure $\mu(B)=\mu(A)/2$.

For c), I have no idea how to produce C...

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: By inner regularity, there exists a compact subset $K\subset A$ such that $\mu(K)>\mu(A)/2$. Now consider the function $x\mapsto\mu(K\cap(-\infty,x]))$...

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks.

Comment: Why not make this a proper answer? I will accept it :)

Comment: Regarding a), you can get a stronger result (Lipschitz continuous) by observing that $f(x + \delta)$ differs at most from $f(x)$ by $\delta,$ which is the length of the interval $(x, x + \delta)$ (when $\delta > 0)$ or the length of the interval $(x + \delta, x)$ (when $\delta < 0).$

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: By inner regularity, there exists a compact subset $K\subset A$ such that $\mu(K)>\mu(A)/2$. Now consider the function $x\mapsto\mu(K\cap(-\infty,x])$...